# Groovy shared library testing pipeline step method with Spock

Tags: jenkins, groovy, mocking, jenkins-pipeline, spock

I have shared library that calls pipeline step method(withCredentials).I am trying to test withCredentails method is being called correctly with sh scripts on calling myMethodToTest but facing error:

```
 class myClass implements Serializable{
    def steps
    public myClass(steps) {this.steps = steps}

    public void myMethodToTest(script, String credentialsId) {
        steps.withCredentials([[$class: ‘UsernamePasswordMultiBinding’, credentialsId: "${credentialsId}", usernameVariable: ‘USR’, passwordVariable: ‘PWD’]]) {
             steps.sh """
                export USR=${script.USR}
                export PWD=${script.PWD}
                $mvn -X clean deploy
             """
          }
     }
}
```

//Mocking

```
class Steps {
   def withCredentials(List args, Closure closure) {}
}

class Script {
    public Map env = [:]
}
```

//Test case

```
def "testMyMethod"(){
        given:
        def steps = Mock(Steps)
        def script = Mock(Script)
        def myClassObj = new myClass(steps)
        script.env['USR'] = "test-user"

        when:
        def result = myClassObj.myMethodToTest(script, credId)

        then:
        1 * steps.withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: "mycredId", usernameVariable: 'USR', passwordVariable: 'PWD']])  
        1 * steps.sh(shString)

        where:
        credId | shString
        "mycredId" | "export USR='test-user'"
```

//Error

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * steps.withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: "mycredId", usernameVariable: ‘USR’, passwordVariable: ‘PWD’]])   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * steps.withCredentials([['$class':'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', 'credentialsId':mycredId, 'usernameVariable’:’USR’, 'passwordVariable':'PWD’]]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more context. There is not enough information to answer your question right now. Show more of your class and also your test. What is it you want to test? What is it you think you should mock? What have you tried so far and what is the exact problem?

Comment: @kriegaex updated question with more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a whole bunch of subtle and not so subtle errors in your code, both test and application classes. So let me provide a new [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in which I fixed everything and commented a few crucial parts inside the test:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59442086

class Script {
  public Map env = [:]
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59442086

class Steps {
  def withCredentials(List args, Closure closure) {
    println "withCredentials: $args, " + closure
    closure()
  }

  def sh(String script) {
    println "sh: $script"
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59442086

class MyClass implements Serializable {
  Steps steps
  String mvn = "/my/path/mvn"

  MyClass(steps) {
    this.steps = steps
  }

  void myMethodToTest(script, String credentialsId) {
    steps.withCredentials(
      [
        [
          class: "UsernamePasswordMultiBinding",
          credentialsId: "$credentialsId",
          usernameVariable: "USR",
          passwordVariable: "PWD"]
      ]
    ) {
      steps.sh """
        export USR=${script.env["USR"]}
        export PWD=${script.env["PWD"]}
        $mvn -X clean deploy
      """.stripIndent()
    }
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59442086

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyClassTest extends Specification {
  def "testMyMethod"() {
    given:
    // Cannot use mock here because mock would have 'env' set to null. Furthermore,
    // we want to test the side effect of 'steps.sh()' being called from within the
    // closure, which also would not work with a mock. Thus, we need a spy.
    def steps = Spy(Steps)
    def myClass = new MyClass(steps)
    def script = new Script()
    script.env['USR'] = "test-user"

    when:
    myClass.myMethodToTest(script, credId)

    then:
    1 * steps.withCredentials(
      [
        [
          class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
          credentialsId: credId,
          usernameVariable: 'USR',
          passwordVariable: 'PWD'
        ]
      ],
      _  // Don't forget the closure parameter!
    )
    // Here we need to test for a substring via argument constraint
    1 * steps.sh({ it.contains(shString) })

    where:
    credId     | shString
    "mycredId" | "export USR=test-user"
  }
}
```

Comment: Too few invocations for:

1 * steps.withCredentials(
            [[
                class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', 
                credentialsId: credId, 
                usernameVariable: ‘USR’, 
                passwordVariable: ‘PWD’
            ]]
        )   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * steps.withCredentials([['class':'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', 'credentialsId':mycredId, 'usernameVariable’:’USR’, 'passwordVariable’:’PWD’]],

Comment: If you just copy all of my code and run it, the test passes. If you just take parts of it, probably you have some inconsistency in your code. Besides, your copied error message without any context or explanation does not help me to answer your question, especially because you did not ask any question. So what is your comment supposed to tell me?

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex, I realized I was using mock instead of spy; issue is resolved..

Comment: how can we mock variable that are being fetched from Jenkins credential store like username/password that are not env variables?

Comment: Please ask a new question, it is unrelated to this one. And please describe better what you want to do via an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: its related to this question if you notice my question fetches user & password from script and not as env var as contradictory to solution suggested

Comment: The question is about why your Spock test was not working, I fixed that for you and you accepted the answer. Now you have a Jenkins-specific question which is no longer related to Spock.

Comment: Besides, I did not change any logic concerning your environment variables, I just copied and fixed your code. I don't even understand what you really want to know, which is why I told you to ask a new question. The new question can point to this one and then explain what is still unclear or not working the way you do it now and what is the expected result. It is strange enough that your test runs a Maven build. In the new question you can explain better why you do that and what you are trying to test.