# groovy spock testing closure with spy

Tags: groovy, nullpointerexception, spock, spy

I have shared library that calls pipeline step method(withCredentials).I am trying to test withCredentials method is being called correctly with sh scripts on calling myMethodToTest but facing error while iterating in withCredentials closure:

**Method To Test**

```
 class myClass implements Serializable{
    def steps
    public myClass(steps) {this.steps = steps}

    public void myMethodToTest(script, credentialsId, dataObject) {
    dataObject.myKeyValue.each {
        steps.withCredentials([[
           $class: ‘UsernamePasswordMultiBinding’, credentialsId: "${credentialsId}",
           usernameVariable: 'USR', passwordVariable: 'PWD']]) {
             steps.sh("git push --set-upstream origin ${it.branch}")
           }
      }
   }      
}
```

**Mocking**

```
class Steps {
   def withCredentials(List args, Closure closure) {}
}

class Script {
    public Map env = [:]
}
```

**Test case**

```
def "testMyMethod"(){
        given:
        def steps = Spy(Steps)
        def script = Mock(Script)
        def myClassObj = new myClass(steps)
        def myDataObject = [
          'myKeyValue' : [['branch' :'mock' ]]
        ]

        when:
        def result = myClassObj.myMethodToTest(script, credId, myDataObject)

        then:
        1 * steps.withCredentials([[
            $class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', 
            credentialsId: "mycredId", 
            usernameVariable: 'USR', 
            passwordVariable: 'PWD'
        ]])  
        1 * steps.sh(shString)

        where:
        credId     | shString
        "mycredId" | "git push --set-upstream origin mock"
```

**Error (it variable becomes null in closure)**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'branch' on null object
```

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59442086/1082681) which I already answered more than a month a go. The code is quasi identical and the error message "too few invocations" too. The NPE you claim to see does not occur. You didn't even incorporate my fix to your sample code. If you cannot present a reproducible version of your problem but just present a duplicate of an old question, nobody can help you. Also in the question title you mention a spy, but your code does not contain any.

Comment: I agree that I have missed out Spy but this isnt duplicate of previously asked question because previous code dint have "it" vairable and on adding comments on the same question you only told me to ask new question and when I am asking new question you are saying its duplicate. I would myself not spend time posting new question if I could get answer to already posted question as I am not here to increase my no. of questions but to get some help.

Comment: You just copied the original, uncorrected pseudo code from your previous question, which is why it is a duplicate. There are wrong, typographical double quotes, a missing parameter in the test causing "too few invocations", a missing method in class `Steps` causing yet another "too few invocations", to name a few. All of these I already fixed in my previous answer which was also accepted. Why can you not just provide a working sample showing the real problem instead of multiple other ones? You never ran your own code, otherwise you would have noticed.

Comment: Furthermore, class `Steps.withCredentials()` never evaluates the closure, also fixed by me already. If you would have based your question on my previous answer instead of started with incomplete and buggy code again, then and only then we all would see the error message you complain about. I just tried. And then Leonard's answer fixes the problem in your application class, but not all the other problems in your sample code. I will post a working sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a case of two nested closures

```
dataObject.myKeyValue.each { // <- first closure it references the map
    steps.withCredentials([[
       $class: ‘UsernamePasswordMultiBinding’, credentialsId: "${credentialsId}",
       usernameVariable: 'USR', passwordVariable: 'PWD']]) { // <- second closure it is null as no parameter is passed to this closure
         steps.sh("git push --set-upstream origin ${it.branch}")
    }
}
```

To fix it you should name the first parameter

```
dataObject.myKeyValue.each { conf ->
    steps.withCredentials([[
       $class: ‘UsernamePasswordMultiBinding’, credentialsId: "${credentialsId}",
       usernameVariable: 'USR', passwordVariable: 'PWD']]) {
         steps.sh("git push --set-upstream origin ${conf.branch}")
    }
}
```

Comment: I still dint get how nested closure change behaviour of "it" in case of Spy (or in general for test case and not execution of actual code in production)? I am trying to understand this as I am not so much inclined to changing actual code and similar behaviour that may happen for .

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361650/groovy-nested-closures-with-using-it it doesn't have anything to do with Spock/Spy stuff, but is normal groovy behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Please accept Leonard's answer, but I want to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a handful of fixes so other people can actually run the test and verify the solution, because even with his answer your code will never run without errors. So here we go (please note my inline comments):

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60044097

class Script {
  public Map env = [:]
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59442086

class Steps {
  def withCredentials(List args, Closure closure) {
    println "withCredentials: $args, " + closure
    // Evaluate closure so as to do something meaningful
    closure()
  }

  // Add missing method to avoid "too few invocations" in test
  def sh(String script) {
    println "sh: $script"
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60044097

class MyClass implements Serializable {
  def steps

  MyClass(steps) { this.steps = steps }

  void myMethodToTest(script, credentialsId, dataObject) {
    // Fix wrong quotes in ‘UsernamePasswordMultiBinding’
    // and incorporate Leonard's solution to the nested closure problem
    dataObject.myKeyValue.each { conf ->
      steps.withCredentials(
        [
          [
            $class          : 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
            credentialsId   : "${credentialsId}",
            usernameVariable: 'USR',
            passwordVariable: 'PWD'
          ]
        ]
      ) {
        steps.sh("git push --set-upstream origin ${conf.branch}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60044097

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyClassTest extends Specification {
  def "testMyMethod"() {
    given:
    def steps = Spy(Steps)
    // Actually this noes not need to be a mock, given your sample code.
    // Maybe the real code is different.
    def script = Mock(Script)
    def myClassObj = new MyClass(steps)
    def myDataObject = [
      'myKeyValue': [['branch': 'mock']]
    ]

    when:
    // Result is never used, actually no need to assign anything
    def result = myClassObj.myMethodToTest(script, credId, myDataObject)

    then:
    1 * steps.withCredentials(
      [
        [
          $class          : 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
          credentialsId   : "mycredId",
          usernameVariable: 'USR',
          passwordVariable: 'PWD'
        ]
      ],
      // Add missing closure parameter placeholder '_' to make the test run
      _
    )
    1 * steps.sh(shString)

    where:
    credId     | shString
    "mycredId" | "git push --set-upstream origin mock"
  }
}
```

**Please note:** Making the test run and making the application do something marginally meaningful is just meant to complete the picture. But actually the problem you were asking about is a ***bug in your application code (using nested closures in an incorrect way).*** The other bugs in both test and application code were just hiding it because the test never even reached the problematic part.

---

**Update:** Your problem boils down to this including two possible solutions (B basically being what Leonard suggested):

```
def evalClosure(Closure closure) {
  closure()
}

// Problem: inner closure's 'it' shadowing outer closure's 'it'
[1, 2].each {
  println "outer closure: it = $it"
  evalClosure {
    println "inner closure: it = $it"
  }
}

println "-" * 30

// Fix A: make inner closure explicitly parameter-less
[1, 2].each {
  println "outer closure: it = $it"
  evalClosure { ->
    println "inner closure: it = $it"
  }
}

println "-" * 30

// Fix B: explicitly rename outer closure's parameter
[1, 2].each { number ->
  println "outer closure: number = $number"
  evalClosure {
    println "inner closure: it = $it"
    println "inner closure: number = $number"
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
outer closure: it = 1
inner closure: it = null
outer closure: it = 2
inner closure: it = null
------------------------------
outer closure: it = 1
inner closure: it = 1
outer closure: it = 2
inner closure: it = 2
------------------------------
outer closure: number = 1
inner closure: it = null
inner closure: number = 1
outer closure: number = 2
inner closure: it = null
inner closure: number = 2
```

Comment: Please note my update, supporting Leonard's explanation of what goes wrong in your application code.